# I didn't catch the class or I didn't arrive the class?

Tags: difference, usage, word-difference

We had a class (university) on Friday that started at 16:00 and ended at 17:00. Together, with my friend, we went to the place by taxi, but, due to a heavy traffic jam, we arrived at 17:30. Now my friend asked me how to refer to it in English. The options are the following:

- We didn't **arrive** the class in time.
- We didn't **reach** the class in time.
- we didn't **catch** the class.

What of those options are off for native English speakers and what are on?

Comment: You didn't **arrive in time for class**.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of things off. I tried to correct it for you, but you apparently denied the corrections. Much of the grammar in the question itself is incorrect. I can only do my best if you want the help. If you weren't going to accept the corrections, I can't help you as much as you might want me to; there's just too much wrong. I'll say this though: no. 2 is probably the only correct one (using "reach"). The one with "catch" sounds odd for a class. It would work for a "ball game" or a "movie" or even a "ride", but a "class" is a little odd.

Comment: @Nick are you talking about me? I didn't see correections from you, therefore I didn't deny something. You are more than welcome to edit mistakes in the post.

Comment: I had, but for whatever reason, they didn't go through. It's not a big deal; I gave you my answer, but I'll edit it again.

Comment: I found who rejected it and why. (I wonder why you don't see it) "Nathan Tuggy reviewed this 7 mins ago: Reject This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner. 2nd: Max reviewed this 25 mins ago: Reject This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner. (more)" then it was rejected by two except for me. Anyway, I edited the question based on your corrections.

Answer (score 2):

The first two possibilities have definite grammar errors - the first should be *We didn’t arrive **at** the class in time.*, the second should be *We didn’t **reach** the class in time.*. The third is grammatically correct, but is an idiom that is not used for that purpose in the area I’m from.

Comment: Thank you 1+^. The second mistake was a typo. I knew that after "did" always become the infinitive form.:) Can you explain for what it is used in the place that you are from? Is it the UK or the US?

Comment: I'm in the northeastern US, and we _catch_ a bus or a train, but not a class. I do know that some of my friends when I was in college would speak of _catching_ a show on TV, but that never sounded right to me. Your edit for the second one makes it correct, and the one that I would use or expect to hear used.

Comment: I understand that you prefer the 2nd option, then what about the 1st option (arrive)? or using it in present perfect simple tense ("We haven't reached the class in time")

Comment: I address the use of ***arrive*** in the answer; a more common alternative is Tᴚoɯɐuo's phrasing. As far as ***We haven't reached the class in time.***, that is grammatically correct, but very definitely *not* common usage, and would imply that not reaching the class in time has occurred multiple times, and that, in fact, reaching it in time has not happened.

Comment: I am very sorry but I didn't understand. You say that both are correct? ("We didn’t reach the class in time" as well as "We didn’t **arrive at** the class in time"?). b.t.w. I saw another suggestion from @Tᴚoɯɐuo in the 1st comment on the post: "You didn't **arrive in** time **for** class"

Comment: ***We didn't arrive at the class in time.*** is correct. ***We didn't reach the class in time.*** is _also_ correct. Tᴚoɯɐuo's suggestion of ***We didn't arrive in time for the class.*** is _also_ correct. All of those discuss a single event.

Comment: ***We haven't reached the class in time.*** implies that you are discussing multiple events, and that ***We reached the class in time.*** has never been true.

Comment: Clear. Thank you very much for the patience and for the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

In AmE, **catch** can certainly be used with broadcasts, at least in my part of the country (southeastern Pennsylvania).

> Did you catch the show on TV last night?

It can also be used with something said:

> I arrived late and didn't catch the first five minutes of the lecture.
>
> What did he just say a second ago? I didn't catch his words.

But we probably wouldn't use **didn't catch** to say that we missed the class *in its entirety*, except to be dismissive of the class as something that was of not great importance to us.

> Sorry, professor, I didn't catch your first five lectures. I was tending to my pet rock, which has been looking a little pekid for the past month.